# How to instantiate chart after the html has rendered in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm fairly new to angular and have been trying to render a chart. The premise is that there will need to be a loading screen shown so long as the chart data isn't ready yet (being pulled from a backend service).

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="!this.chartData.length; then show_loading; else show_graph"></div>

<ng-template #show_loading>
  Loading...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #show_graph>
      <div id="clubs-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</ng-template>
```

**Component**

```
...
...
// regular component declarations
...
...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Chart code goes in here

    this.browserOnly(() => {
      am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

      // define and configure the chart
      let chart = am4core.create('clubs-chart', am4charts.PieChart3D);
     
     // chart customization
       ...
       ...
       ...
      this.chart = chart;
    });
  }


 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.dashboard_data().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        // get data
        this.chartData = data;
      },
      error: (err) => {},
      complete: () => {
        this.chart.data = this.chartData; // populate the graph with data
      },
    });
  }
```

The above works fine when I don't have the `*ngIf` to switch between the loading and the actual chart view. The moment I introduce the `ngIf` to dynamically switch between the templates, when the graph is being initialized by the line: `let chart = am4core.create('clubs-chart', am4charts.PieChart3D);`, I get an error stating that the 'clubs-chart' container is not found. I know this is because the ngIf makes it so that the acual html isn't even rendered yet at the time of initialization. It appears to be more of a timing issue more than anything.

How do I go about doing this the right way? I've noticed that some people suggest making use of `ngAfterViewChecked()`, I notice that `ngAfterViewChecked()` gets called multiple times, and does not have any sort of an object that tells me what's changed or what's been rendered / re-rendered (assuming that my understanding of `ngAfterViewChecked` is correct)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is retrieved from an API call asynchronously. You're dependent on ajax call to finish. And once that is finished you want to render the chart.
Few things I noticed here -

- Chart rendering logic and data fetching not in sync.
- Chart rendering logic triggers before relevant DOM added to the DOM.
- `ngAfterViewInit` is the right hook, used in an incorrect place.

To solve this problem you consider creating Angular Components for this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-chart',
  template: `<div #chart style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>`,
}) 
export class MyChartComponent {
  @Input() chartData: any; // change type based on what you have

  @ViewChild('chart') chart: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.browserOnly(() => {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

     // define and configure the chart
     let chart = am4core.create(this.chart.nativeElement, am4charts.PieChart3D);
 
     // chart customization
     ...
     ...
     this.chart = chart;
   });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="!chartData.length; else show_graph">
   <my-chart [chartData]="chartData"></my-chart>
</div>

<ng-template #show_loading>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```

Now you can see what exactly is happening The `my-chart` component is rendered when `*ngIf="chartData.length"` has value. So same code you can move inside `ngAfterViewInit` of `MyChartComponent`.

By doing this

1. You have segregated the code
2. Create a separate component for re-usability.
3. Also we removed `clubs-chart` id from components and used `ViewChild` to pass DOM element to `am4core.create` method.